# PHP how to turn a pattern into a regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

How can I make a pattern become a regex?

For intance I have this `:id` as one of my url patterns, I want to turn it into a regex so that it can match `1` or `2`, or `3`.

```
$requestUrl = 'foo/1/';
$regex = 'foo/:id/';

$match = preg_match($regex, $requestUrl);
```

So `$match` should be `true`.

I have this,

```
$route = 'foo/:id/';
var_dump((preg_match_all('`(/|\.|)\[([^:\]]*+)(?::([^:\]]*+))?\](\?|)`', $route, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)));
```

but I get `int 0` as the result.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? The regex should be fairly simple, something like that:

```
foo/[0-9]+/
```

In case you want to be more precise and only match if there is nothing else in that string, then you have to add anchors for line end beginning and ending:

```
^foo/[0-9]+/$
```

Note that this is just the plain regex, if you want to feed it to the function `preg_match()`, then you have to take some additional steps because of how that function works:

```
preg_match('/^foo\/[0-9]+\/$/', $requestUrl)
```

A good idea to start writing your own regular expressions is to use one of the many online regex testing tools. They allow to develop your expression step by step. And it certainly always is a good idea to take a look at a functions documentation if you run into problems using it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

About automatically converting your pattern into a regular expression: this is not easy to answer in a general way. For your example, as I understand it, the approach would be like that probably:

```
$requestUrl = 'foo/1/';
$requestPattern = 'foo/:id/';

preg_match('/^(.*\/):id(\/.*)$/', $requestPattern, $tokens);
define('DELIM', '/');
$requestRegex = sprintf(DELIM.'^%s[0-9]+%s$'.DELIM, 
                        preg_quote($tokens[1], DELIM), 
                        preg_quote($tokens[2], DELIM));

echo preg_match($requestRegex, $requestUrl) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Explanation: with the first, preparing call to `preg_match()` you extract those parts from the pattern that exist *beside* the placeholder `:id`. You can then in the following call to `sprintf()` use those parts to construct your regular expression. The calls to `preg_quote()` are required to pevent any `/` characters which occur inside the parts to be interpreted as delimiter characters inside the created regex. To make that easier to understand I introduced the constant `DELIM` which only as an example is set to `/` here.

Obviously the solution depends on the nature of the pattern which I can only guess by the single example you gave...

Comment: Thanks but I get this error with your suggestion `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\...`

Comment: Could you please read my answer to the end? This looks like you tried the second version by putting it into the function call. Obviously that will not work. I said so in my answer.

Comment: aww got it. thanks. but how can I turn `'foo/:id/'` into `'/^foo\/[0-9]+\/$/'`?

Comment: Hm, this is nothing that can be answered in general. This question only makes sense if you have a "typical pattern" with variants, so that a transfer rule can be stated. All that is clear right now is a string holding a numerical part in it. That is what the regex as it is already takes care of. Let me ask this way: _why can't you simply use the regex as shown above in its literal form_?

Comment: OK, I gave it a try, check the modified answer :-)

Comment: thanks for the edit. I have an idea - what about using `preg_replace` to replace `:id` with `[0-9]+`?

Comment: Sure, that is also possible. But not that easy, since you still have to quote the parts of the regex. So you have to replace every part of the pattern, not just the placeholder. The placeholder itself is replaced by the numerical group pattern as shown. The part before and behind must be replaced by quoted versions of themselves. Otherwise the regex will not match or, more likely, not even compile but generate a runtime error. So the outcome would be more or less the same to the approach shown above.

Comment: thanks for that. what if I have this to match `foo/:id/:name/`? preg_replace seems to be easier - `preg_replace("/(?::([^:\]]*+))/", "[0-9]+", $input)`.

Comment: No, as said before this will not work. Because of the missing quoting of the remaining parts. But it looks like you are on your track now. So good luck, I am sure you will succeed!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I would suggest:

> 1. The regex pattern needs to have delimiters at each end (I've used `!`)
> 2. If you want to grab digits specifically create a capture group with `( )`
> 3. Simplify your pattern using a meta character like `\d` or character class `[0-9]`
>
>    (for multiple digits use `+` (match one or more digits) or `*` (zero or more)

Here's an example of this in use:

```
$regex = "!foo\/(\d)\/!";
$requestUrl = "foo/1/";

$result = preg_match($regex, $requestUrl);
```

To practice and refine your regex try one of the online tools:

https://regex101.com/r/sB3bH9/1